# Не применяется локализация в дочерней теме wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, локализация

Сайт на `wordpress`. Создал локализованный перевод темы, хочу поместить его в папку дочерней темы **lang** Все делаю в соответствии с мануалом [по ссылке](http://wp-kama.ru/function/load_child_theme_textdomain) В функции дочерней темы `functions.php` прописываю:

```
/**
 * Child theme language
 */
function my_child_theme_setup() {
    $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lang';
    var_dump($path);
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'child_theme_language', $path );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

Но локализация не срабатывает...
`var_dump` выводит `string(67) "/hosting/home/domen/public_html/wp-content/themes/bolid-child/lang"`
Файлы перевода созданы правильно, т.к. если их закинуть по аналогичному пути родительской темы - все работает. В чем же причина?

Comment: Проверьте правильность имени файла перевода. Имя должно выглядеть так `child_theme_language-ru_RU.mo`.

Comment: @Себастьян Перейро хорошая попытка, мне нравится, но не работает..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел самое правильное решение:

```
/**
 * Child theme language
 */
function my_child_theme_setup() {
    $path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lang';
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'child_theme_language', $path );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

Чтобы файл локализации можно было поместить в папку с дочерней темой нужно, чтобы обязательно! *первый параметр в функции load_child_theme_textdomain() совпадал со вторым в вызове функции перевода*! в данном случае **'child_theme_language'**

```
_e( 'My translatable text goes here.', 'child_theme_language' );
```

и тогда названия файлом должны быть **ru_RU.po** и **ru_RU.mo**